# Dropwizard Metrics Get Average Items Per REST Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics

I would like to use Dropwizard metrics to get the average number of items in a list for each request my spring boot REST controller services. My controller takes in a string which is serialized into a `RequestCollection`. `RequestCollection` has a single `List<Integer> ids` field that consists of a list of ids. I'd like to know what the average number of items in the `ids` field is across all requests.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {

    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    public ApiController(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        this.metricRegistry = metricRegistry;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getFooBarred(
            @RequestParam(value = "params") String requestItem
    ) {
        RequestCollection request = request = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .readValue(requestItem, RequestCollection.class);

        // Add metric here to metricRegistry for average number of items 
        // in RequestCollection across all requests.
        // RequestCollection has a single property which is a List<Integer> ids

        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

Here is the `RequestCollection` class whose `ids` field I would like to measure across all requests.

**RequestCollection**

```
public class RequestCollection {
    private List<Integer> ids;

    public RequestCollection() {
        this.ids = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the [5 main metric types](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/manual/core.html), Guages, Counters, Histograms, Meters, and Timers, the one that suits your need the best would probably be the [`Histogram`](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/manual/core.html#man-core-histograms), which "measures the distribution of values in a stream of data: e.g., the number of results returned by a search".

```
Histogram itemCount
    = metrics.histogram(MetricRegistry.name(RequestCollection.class, "id-count"));
```

The in each request, just update the histogram with the count for the collection.

```
itemCount.update(collection.getIds().size());
```

The reporting will give you a few different of statistics, along with the mean, which is what you want

```
-- Histograms ----------------------------
com.example.RequestCollection.id-count
             count = 100
               min = 0
               max = 99
              mean = 45.47
            stddev = 31.65
            median = 45.00
              75% <= 73.00
              95% <= 94.00
              98% <= 99.00
              99% <= 99.00
            99.9% <= 99.00
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! How long is the histogram data saved for? I.e., is it a moving window across a particular time span?

Comment: It should be store for the life of the application.